# Oscillation in the FTIR spectrum

Tags: experimental-physics, spectroscopy, infrared-radiation

An FTIR spectrum was measured for me (device from Alignment and MCT Detector) and since I'm not very familiar with FTIR I'm looking for some advice. The absorbance spectrum was obtained by measuring the reflectance of a reference sample and the actual sample. The reference sample was stainless steel and the actual sample was probably stainless steel coated with dopamine and a peptide. The spectrum shows some kind of oscillations. [image]

It was suggested that the oscillation is due to interference caused by the dopamine coating. The coating could act like a thin film. Unfortunately, I haven't found anything paper/ literature supporting the suggestion.
Have you seen something similar?

Comment: Cross posted: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/175999/79678.